# Fixing my scroll to a smooth scroll on your webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the navigation smooth scroll to their approiate section of the page.  Right now my navigation goes to the section of the page I want it too, but it doesn't smooth scroll.

I have included the smoothscroll.js in the js folder and called it in my html through this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/smoothscroll.js">
```

I have added these scripts to the end of the body tag after the end of my wrapper

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/_jq.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/_jquery.placeholder.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Not sure why it is not smooth scroll and why it is not keeping the navigation bar as I scroll up n down.  I also added anchor points above the container containing the about us and contact section.
seen here:

```
<a href="#aboutus" class="smoothScroll">
<span class="label-nav">
About Us
</span>
</a>
```

Any advice? Thanks!

extra scripts:

```
<script src="js/activeaxon_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/animationEnigne.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/easypiecharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/ie-fixes.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js" type="text/javascript">   </script> 
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.eislideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.infinitescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jQuery.scrollPoint.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.tipsy.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jQuery.XDomainRequest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/retina.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/tweetable.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/zeina.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What smooth scroll library are you using?

Comment: you should try to include the `jquery.min.js` **before** all the other jQuery dependend scripts. Also use the console of your browser to see any errors created by javascript.

Comment: @Sebsemillia that does fix my naivgation staying at the top of the page, but now when I click for example about us or any button, it instantly goes to the middle of the paragraph for that section.  When I click the same nav btn again then it correctly aligns.  Its not a one click event.  I will click about us...it goes to the middle of that paragraph..i scroll up to the top of the page..click about us again and still goes to the middle...not sure why.  I think its not taking the navigation into account when scroll.  It also does not smooth scroll...

Comment: How you initialize smooth scrolling?

Comment: @ColinSchoen found the smoothscroll.js file from the internet..where would I be able to know which library it is...still new to this.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil I took a js file that demoed the smooth scroll, not sure why its not working for me

Comment: You need to link us to either the script and preferably the docs of the script.

Comment: Not all smooth-scroll scrips see the same.

Comment: @Drew most probably the fixed navbar messes up the scroll position. This is more a CSS fixable issue I think. Colin is right, we need to see more of the scripts and preferrably html / css. Best is you create a working jsfiddle with you problem. Without this it is very hard for us to help you more.

Comment: @Sebsemillia let me see...here are all the scripts underneth the other scripts i wrote....i will attach above

Comment: @Sebsemillia i have added the extra scripts....what part of the html/css would you need to see.  Still learning.  This is also a purchased template I am working with